# SOAP in swift getting 400 error

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I am working on SOAP web services in swift every thing is fine but I am getting 400 error bad request can you guys please help me.

Please check link given below for

> http://www.bincrm.com/IFIPL/IFIPLDetails.asmx?op=Select
>
> http://www.bincrm.com/IFIPL/IFIPLDetails.asmx?op=Select for SOAPmessage

class ViewController: UIViewController,XMLParserDelegate {

```
    var currentElement:String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let SqlQuery = "Select top 1 RTRSN,RTName,RTVILLANO,contactcellno,isnull(contactno,'-')as contactno,isnull(contactmail,'-')as contactmail,replace(Rtaddress1,',','^^')as Rtaddress1,isnull(cityname,'-')as cityname,isnull(pincode,'-')as pincode, isnull(country,'-')as country, convert(nvarchar(11),DOB,106)as DOB,isnull(marital_status,'-')as marital_status,isnull(Bloodgroup,'-')as Bloodgroup from tblResident where RTVILLANO='sdm 45' and  contactcellno='9566703089'"


        let Connname = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Covaisoft;User ID=cpc;Password=C0va!C@re34&"


        let is_SoapMessage: String = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:tns='http://www.bincrm.com/IFIPL/' xmlns:types='http://www.bincrm.com/IFIPL/encodedTypes' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body soap:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'><tns:Select><Connname xsi:type='xsd:string'>\(Connname)</Connname><SqlQuery xsi:type='xsd:string'>\(SqlQuery)</SqlQuery></tns:Select></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"






        let is_URL: String = "http://www.bincrm.com/ifipl/IFIPLDetails.asmx"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL)! as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var _: NSError?

        lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        lobj_Request.addValue("www.bincrm.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       // lobj_Request.addValue(String(count(is_SoapMessage)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        //lobj_Request.addValue("223", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        lobj_Request.addValue("http://www.bincrm.com/IFIPL/Select", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response!)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("Body: \(strData!)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error:\(String(describing: error))")
            }
            let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: data!)
            xmlParser.delegate = self
            xmlParser.parse()
            xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true

        })
        task.resume()
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        currentElement = elementName
    }
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if self.currentElement == "SelectResponse"
        {
            print("-------\(string)-------")
        }    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Reason for this error is you are missing something in your request, have you run it on some SOAP client and see what it returns?

Comment: yeah,if I change the connection name then it is working fine but with this connection name it is not working, but in browser it is working fine

Comment: Any console output (errors, warnings, etc.) ? URLs use http, have you setup ATS correctly ?

Comment: I have found the error, in connection name the password ends with '&' so I have replaced it with &amp; then it is working fine.Thank you user1000 for your response